# How to make flutter return a list of node names of firebase

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, flutter-web, stateful, dropdownbutton

```
`final dbRef = database.child("Blocos");
  dbRef.onValue.listen((event) => {
    event.snapshot.children.forEach((child) {
      if (child.key != null) {
       item.add(child.key.toString());
      }
    })
  });
  print(item);
```

[Firebase Rtdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etO9d.png)

when I print it only appears [], how do I make a list of the type [word1, word2] appear? I intend to use the list to make a dropdownbutton afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to check, is "blocos" has data or not. You can print on event curly brackets first. I think, the mistakes is you're not make sure, is "blocos" has data or not. Hopefully can help you. Thank you

Comment: I have data in the database, I believe that the problem is the execution of the program. But i dont have any idea how to solve it.